# How do I find the angle limits in polar integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

If I have $$\int^0_{-\sqrt{3}} \int^{\frac{y}{\sqrt3}}_{-\sqrt{4-y^2}} \frac{2}{1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dxdy $$
We can say that $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and the limits of r can be found by sketching the region from the original limits fig (1). and rewrite the integral as:

$$\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \int^2_0 \frac{2r}{1+r}drd\theta $$
How do I find $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.
[image]

Comment: How did you find 0 and 2?

Comment: The radius $r_1$ and $r_2$ of the circle from the given boundaries

Comment: Can you please show all the steps? $\theta\in[0,2\pi[$.

Comment: @Sebastiano ok I added the sketch of the boundaries so it's easier to understand, The hatched area is the region

Comment: $$\int_{\frac{4\pi}3}^{\pi} \int^2_0 \frac{2r}{1+r}drd\theta $$

Comment: @Quanto can you explain why and will it be correct if I said that $\theta_1 =\pi$ and $\theta_2 = \frac{2}{3} \pi$ ?

Comment: The angle limits identify two rays going out of the origin. The two rays touch the area of integration and all of your area of integration lies between those two rays. Assuming you got the inner integral's limits correct, your area of integration has to touch each of the rays along all points from $r=0$ to $r=2.$ Which two rays touch the area of integration in that way?

Comment: @DavidK I'm assuming a ray in direction of $-\hat {i}$ and one in and another one in the direction  of (-2,-$\sqrt3$)?

Comment: @YoussefMohamed $\theta_1=\pi$ and $\theta_2 =\frac{4\pi}3$.